# Codeigniter running background scripts with same configuration and libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fellows,
I want when I do a fileupload on codeigniter when upload finished to run a background process.

The background process will read the file and will insert data on my db. What I want is to the background script (that will be written in php) to be able to use codeignter's configuration and query builder. Because codeingiter's methods are more convenient than uusinhg vanila php.

I know to I can execute stuff on the background via exec and that's now what I am asking. I am asking how the executed script can use codeigniter's methods and libraries.

Comment: Are you asking how to upload files using codeigniter, or are you asking how to upload files using codeigniter and websockets?

Comment: I am asking on how to run background proceces on codeigniter using codeigniter methods and libraries such as query builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [Running via the CLI](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html). It may be possible to pass what they show as a terminal command as the argument to `exec` and achieve what you want.